# Nested if inside each (Handlebars template in Express app)

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

This morning I figured I'd finally take a look at Handlebars by throwing together a quick Express app. I'm enjoying it so far (and I think I prefer Handlebars to Jade) but I have a problem. The app I'm playing with is (yet another) basic CMS using Mongo. On the /posts/index page, I'm checking for and displaying posts with:

```
{{#if posts}}
  {{#each posts}}
    <h4>{{title}}
    <p>{{content}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  <p>There are no posts.</p>
{{/if}}
```

This is simple and works as expected but I was then wondering about adding something like an *Edit* button at the bottom of each post. I'd like to condition the visibility of this based on *user*. If logged in (I'm using Passport's local strategy), I can easily see the user's details with:

```
{{#if user}}
  {{user.name}}
{{/if}}
```

The problem, however, is that I can't seem to get that *if user* check working **inside** the *each* above. Is this possible in Handlebars? In Jade, in the past, I've just used something like:

```
if(posts.length)
  each post in posts
    #{post.title}
    if(user)
      ...
```

For the sake of clarity, the *get* route for the posts page is:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
    res.render('posts/index', {
      title: 'Posts',
      user: req.user,
      posts: posts,
    });
  });
});
```

As mentioned, I'm really new to Handlebars so I'm hoping this is something really obvious. Thanks in advance and I hope you all have a great NYE!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- You don't need to surround the `each` with an `if`, `each...else` works.
- If you try to access `user` within the `each`, you'll actually be trying to access `posts.user`. You can access the parent context using `../`.

E.g.

```
{{#each posts}}
  <h4>{{title}}
  <p>{{content}}</p>
  {{#if ../user}}
    {{../user.name}}
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
  <p>There are no posts.</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: @matt and an important one too, since its not on the official http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html] , only on the github page (https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#paths). tnx a bunch :)

Comment: Good answer. As I'm new to handlebars I didn't thought about the context!